# Test Class code coverage on Redir method

Tags: apex, unit-test

Test class is failing with an error:

**Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="DispatcherContactEditController"  
    action="{!nullValue(redir.url, urlFor($Action.Contact.Edit, contact.id, null, true))}">
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
   public class DispatcherContactEditController {
    public DispatcherContactEditController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public PageReference getRedir() {
        Contact c = [Select id, recordtypeid From Contact Where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        PageReference newPage;

        if (c.recordtypeid == '111111111111') {
            newPage = Page.Contact_Edit_1;
          } else {
            newPage = new PageReference('/' + c.id + '/e');
            newPage.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
        }

        newPage.getParameters().put('id', c.id);
           return newPage.setRedirect(true);
    }
      private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
static testMethod void DispatcherContactEditControllertest() {
    Account acc = New Account();
    acc.Name = 'TestAccount';
    insert acc;
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName='testLast',firstName='testFirst');
    insert con;
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(cont);
    Test.startTest();
    DispatcherContactEditController controller = new DispatcherContactEditController(stdController);
    PageReference pr = controller.getRedir();
   // controller.contactId = 'testid';
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

**Test Class Error:** System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting exception in this query

```
Contact c = [Select id, recordtypeid From Contact Where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

In your test class update this line

```
Test.startTest();
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', con.Id);
    DispatcherContactEditController controller = new DispatcherContactEditController(stdController);
```

Because in your query if you will not get any record then it will always fail. So its better if you get record in a list and then check size of list and if its greater then 0 then assign it to variable.

Comment: be good idea to also mock the contact with the right recordTypeId too